# inputtype decimal and signed value issue android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I have used inputtype

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
```

I have to make check if the input type is equal to numberdecimal OR  numbersigned then not to execute some set of code.

I found mapping of

```
//numberDecimal to InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL (int 8192)
//numberSigned to     InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED (int 4096)
```

Code logic is like this

```
if (inputType != InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL
                        ||  inputType!=InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED)
{
                  // Some logic here
}
```

but still this code is getting executed even if inputtype is decimal or signed  numbers. 
 So i checked the value of inputType in logs which is coming as 12290.

Now how this value is coming to 12290 if I take OR of (4096|8192) it is coming as 12288 .

```
 0001000000000000 (4096)
 0010000000000000 (8192)
 0011000000000000 (12288)
```

Should i do hard coding of 12290 to satisfy this condition ?

Comment: ya i got the same issue then i solved into bitwise operation

Answer (score 0):

`12290 = "numberDecimal|numberSigned"
= InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL // 8192
+ InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED // 4096
+ InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER // 2`

Comment: Please **edit** your answer to make it human readable. There is a reason for all those "how to use markup" explanations around the editor window. And that preview functionality.